# Cannot connect to a network mysql database

Tags: mysql, windows-store

I am building a Windows Store application who is intended to interact with a MySql database located at a server in my local network.
I am using MySQL connector/net RT to connect(which works on my testing localhost DB), the problem is that for some reason i cannot connect to the network database; although i can get a successful connection with a different Win32 app, who has the same connection string.
i disabled the firewall, i created a new user on the host to access from my AP, etc. Can somebody tell me what am I doing wrong?

C#

```
using MySQL.Data.MySqlClient;
using Windows.UI.Popups;

MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("server=1.1.1.1;port=3306;database=mydb;uid=user;password=****;");
try{
    connection.Open();
    connection.Close();
}
catch (MySqlException e){
    MessageDialog md = new MessageDialog(e.ToString());
    md.ShowAsync();
}
```

//Exception:
failed to Open Connection

Comment: Can you connect to your database using the same configuration (IP address, etc.) using some other tool like [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)?

Comment: yes indeed, i tested on MySQL workbench and i can manipulate my remote database successfully; but still no connection with Visual Studio 2013 compiler

Answer (score 0):

This is how I connect. Hope it Helps

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class ClassMySqlConnect
Public Shared SQLConnect As String = "Server=YOURSERVERADDRESS; User Id=YOURID; Password=YOURPASSWORD;Database=YOURDATABASENAME"
Public Function connect(ByVal PlayerID As String) As String


    Dim SQLConnection = New MySqlConnection
    SQLConnection.ConnectionString = SQLConnect
    Try
        If SQLConnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            SQLConnection.Open()
            'Return "Sucessfully Connected to MySql Database"
        Else
            SQLConnection.Open()
            ' Return "Connection is closed"
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' Return ex.ToString()
    End Try



    Dim SQLStatement As String = "INSERT INTO Toons (PlayerID) Values('" + PlayerID + "')"
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
    With cmd
        .CommandText = SQLStatement
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
        .Connection = SQLConnection
        .ExecuteNonQuery()
    End With

    Return "successfully saved"

End Function

End Class
```